# jQuery Datatables - Using controls affects click function

Tags: jquery, click, datatables, row, handler

Weird, intermittent problems are hard to solve without all the code, but here goes (I'm getting desperate):

I have an HTML table that uses Datatables:

```
$('#DatagridTable').dataTable({ 
    'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
});
```

I have a jQuery click event for the table that sends the contents of the first cell in the clicked row to a form and then submits the form. Here's the function:

```
//  On row click, go to single-view page
$('.c_grid_tr').click(function() {  
    var equipID = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    //  Fill hidden text box on form with value to post
    $('#singleRowID').val(equipID);
    //  Post form
    $('#formEquipment').submit();
});
```

The click function works fine until I use any of the navigation features of Datatables (go to another page, sort, change the number of records displayed). But after doing any of these, my click event only works sporadically, seemingly on random rows. I've looked a the HTML source, but the rows where the click event works and those where it doesn't are identical. Here's an example of two rows that are rendered in Firefox:

```
<tr class='c_grid_tr'>
    <td style='display:none;'>817</td>
    <td class='c_grid_td'>Ground Optic #1</td>
    <td class='c_grid_td'>Zeiss</td>
    <td class='c_grid_td'>950</td>
    <td class='c_grid_td'>DTY</td>
    <td class='c_grid_td'>Storage Facility</td>
    <td class='c_grid_td'>Y</td>
</tr><tr class='c_grid_tr'>
    <td style='display:none;'>818</td>
    <tdclass='c_grid_td'>Ground Optic #1</td>
    <td class='c_grid_td'>Zeiss</td>
    <td class='c_grid_td'>950</td>
    <td class='c_grid_td'>DTZ</td>
    <td class='c_grid_td'>Storage Facility</td>
    <td class='c_grid_td'>Y</td>
</tr>
```

The first row responds to the click event. The second one does not, and this problem occurs ONLY after I have sorted, changed pages, or changed the number of displayed records. I put an alert box in my click event, and that doesn't fire, so I know that the click event isn't even activated when I click the second row.

As always, thanks for any on-topic advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely that certain columns were included in the first load (when the click event was bound), but on subsequent loads you're not reloading the whole page, just the table, so the event isn't rebound to the new elements.

You're going to want to unbind and rebind the event on table draw, I think, i.e.:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
    $('.c_grid_tr').unbind();
    //  On row click, go to single-view page
    $('.c_grid_tr').click(function() {  
        var equipID = $(this).find('td:first').text();
        //  Fill hidden text box on form with value to post
        $('#singleRowID').val(equipID);
        //  Post form
        $('#formEquipment').submit();
    });
}
```

Comment: Colleen, sorry for the delay - taking care of a sick parent. Your solution worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help- Grateful noob. : |

Answer (score 1):

try using a javascript onclick function call inline and pass the element with it, like:

```
<tr onclick="updateRow(this)">
```

If you need a unique selector for the tr and have control over the output, use an index for the id or record id like:

```
<tr id="[create in the output]">
```

Comment: he's using datatables, which means he doesn't actually create the html rows. Adding onclick functions in this manner would therefore be a little difficult.

Comment: Duly noted. However, it would helpful to know if the developer is able to modify the markup output to add id's to the rows, server side and/or with templating.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I used Colleen's solution below, but I'd have gone this route if I needed to. I'm drawing the table with PHP before binding it to Datatables, so there was probably a workable solution somewhere in your answer. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You're welcome Stanton. As you get into displaying larger tables with paged results, and need to order and/or sort across more than one page of displayed results... then something like this combined with ajax,  templates, and json will be beneficial.